# Is it a scam if they ask for my bank account username and password instead of the account number?

Tags: scams

Someone I met told me he was in the military and was willing to give me “allowance” each week. But, his excuse was that he was not allowed to leave base so he had a “bank manager” that took care of all his money. So he asked me for my login credentials and said he’d deposit a check of $1600, I take $600 and send the rest back to somewhere he’s not even in. 
I think he gave me a fake number, because I asked to talk to his bank manager and he only answers my texts. 
Please just clarify the stupidity of this for me. Thanks.

Comment: See also: https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/71327/is-it-a-scam-if-a-military-commander-from-the-army-deposit-money-into-my-account

Comment: Ask yourself, why would he be giving you an allowance?

Comment: YES.  YES.  THIS IS A SCAM.

Comment: He can drain your account with the username and password.

Comment: @JamesTrotter Even if someone wants to give you an allowance, why would they send you more than you've earned and ask you to send the extra back? How do people fall for this?